# Show a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm working through the proof of Hasse's theorem and I think I need to show that the polynomial $x^4 - 2ax^2 - 8bx + a^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $a$, $b$ are integers and $p$ is prime.  Wolfram Alpha repliably informs me that it is but I can't see how to show it?

Comment: Another case of WA flunking a test...or, perhaps, the input written in WA was incorrect.

Comment: Whenever $p>2$ you can arrange $1$ to be a zero of your polynomial by selecting the value of $b$ correctly (you get a linear equation for $b$ be plugging in $x=1$). The same holds for any non-zero element of $\Bbb{F_p}$. Therefore you most likely don't need to show that this is irreducible. Please give a bit more context, and may be we can help. WA cannot do this reliably unless you give explicit values to $a, b, p4 (I think?), so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be true as stated. Take $a=b=1$ and $p=2$. Then
$$
x^4-2ax^2-8bx+a^2=x^4-2x^2-8x+1=x^4+1=(x+1)^4.
$$
Also, if you don'tt like $p=2$, this is reducible for $p=5$:
$$
x^4-2x^2-8x+1=(x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 3)(x + 2).
$$

And, of course, for $a=b=0$ is is obvious, too.